# How to get Script instace corresponding to an init script in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

How to get instance of [`org.gradle.api.Script`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Script.html) corresponding to the initscript in the initscript itself?

Comment: I wrote an answer based of my understanding of your question.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Script.html :

> This interface is implemented by all Gradle scripts to add in some Gradle-specific methods. As your compiled script class will implement this interface, you can use the methods and properties declared by this interface directly in your script.

This means that all your Gradle scripts (project , settings or init scripts) implement this `Script` interface, so you can simply use `this` within your script to access the corresponding `Script` instance.

For example if you want to access the `Script.buildscript` and print the script location:

```
println "Current script file: " + ((Script)this).buildscript.getSourceFile()
```

- From a Project build script this should print :

`Current script file: /path/to/project/build.gradle`

- From the Init Script (if `init.gradle` is in USER_HOME/.gradle/ directory):

`Current script file: /path/to/userhome/.gradle/init.gradle`